# Scrapy Spider stops before crawling anything

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, scrapy

So I have a django project and a views.py from which I want to call a Scrapy spider if a certain condition is met. The crawler seems to be called just fine but terminates so quickly that the parse function is not called (that is my assumption at least) as shown below:

```
2020-11-16 18:51:25 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'products',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'crawler.spiders',
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['crawler.spiders.my_spider'],
 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, '
               'like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'}
2020-11-16 18:51:25 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: ******
2020-11-16 18:51:25 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
['https://www.tesco.com/groceries/en-GB/products/307358055']
2020-11-16 18:51:26 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-11-16 18:51:26 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
[16/Nov/2020 18:51:26] "POST /productsinfo HTTP/1.1" 200 2
```

views.py

```
def get_info():
  url = data[product]["url"]
  setup()
  runner(url)
  products = []
  serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
  return(Response(serializer.data))

@wait_for(timeout=10.0)
def runner(url):
    crawler_settings = Settings()
    configure_logging()
    crawler_settings.setmodule(my_settings)
    runner = CrawlerRunner(settings=crawler_settings)
    d = runner.crawl(MySpider, url=url)
```

my_spider.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from itemloaders.processors import TakeFirst
from crawler.items import ScraperItem


class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myspider"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        link = kwargs.get('url')
        self.start_urls = [link]
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url=self.start_urls[0], callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        do stuff
```

Can anyone guide me towards why this is happening and how I can solve it?

Comment: A [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) could get you more feedback, or even help you figure out the issue for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why that is, however I remember running into similar issues.
Could you please alter your `__init__` and `start_requests` methods to the following and tell me about the outcome:

```py
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.link = kwargs.get('url')
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url=self.link, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: I have tried your solution and it did the same thing. However, I added a return clause in the runner(url), `return d`, and it seems to have solved it. Thanks for your help tho.